# Angular test a router event like NavigationEnd

Tags: angular, testing, routes

I'm searching from last 2 days to simulate a router event in order to test

```js
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

In this block :

```js
      ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
          if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
            return;
          }
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          if (this.object.attribut1) {
            this.loadSomething();
          }
          if (this.object.attribut2) {
            this.loadSomething2();
          }
        });
      }
```

So i need to simulate this : this.router.events.subscribe((evt) in test

I already have a test for this window.scrollTo (that works but only if window.scrollTo is out of the router event) :

```js
      it('calls window.scrollTo', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(endpoint);
    expect(req).toBeDefined();
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    req.flush(MOCKED);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(spyScrollTo).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I found many examples but nothing help me and i never understand theses examples.

I will be really thanksfull if someone got explanations or examples
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock the router and provide the event object.

Something like this:

```
describe('YourComponent', () => {
  let component: YourComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<YourComponent>;
  let eventsStub = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  let routerStub = {
    events: eventsSub,
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        YourComponent,
      ],
      providers: [
        // merge the two mocks like this !!
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub },
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
           snapshot: {
             queryParams: of({})
            },
            queryParams: of({}),
            queryParamMap: of({}),
           params: of({id: 'something'})
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    let mockNav = new NavigationEnd(1, 'any', 'any');
    // make events have the mockNav listed above
    eventsSub.next(mockNav);
    // this detectChanges will make ngOnInit be called
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('calls window.scrollTo', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
    expect(spyScrollTo).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // your other tests
  });
});
```

When running these tests, put a log in the `subscribe` to ensure the test has traversed it:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
          if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
            return;
          }
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          console.log('After scrollTo!!!'); // !! remove when done but make sure you see this
          if (this.object.attribut1) {
            this.loadSomething();
          }
          if (this.object.attribut2) {
            this.loadSomething2();
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: It's look like somehting i have ever try but it breack my old tests, i will check that more deeper, Thx :)

Comment: Check out my edit, you can merge the two mocks like this. It seems like your component relies on both `Router` and `ActivatedRoute`, so you can mock them like how I showed you above. If you show me your whole test and component, I think I can help you better.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm doing :/ i will show you my beforeEach and one of my test